# Count number of Instances of Char in a given String Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, char

Simple problem.

Given a String, I want to be able to enter a letter and then have my function count the number of times that letter appears in a string.

```
countLetters :: String -> Char -> Int
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With

```
countLetters :: String -> Char -> Int
countLetters str c = length $ filter (== c) str
```

This gets only the characters in `str` that equal `c`, then computes the length of that.

Comment: This suffers the performance penalty of having to traverse the entire input string once to filter, and then traverse the result of that to get the length.

Comment: But aren't `length` and `filter` both lazy functions?  I would imagine that GHC could optimize a simple case like that to produce a single loop.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the number of calls you'd like to make to one `String`. Simple solution would be to just read every character in the string, if it matches the one you're looking for, increase the counter.

Now, if you're mapping over something with a counter, you can obviously use `fold`:

```
countLetters xs x = foldl (\count char -> if char == x then (count + 1) else count) 0 xs
```

However, if you want to do many queries, it makes more sense to build the lookup table (i.e. *sort*) first. Then you can get the number of repetitions of arbitrary character in `O(1)` (the whole algorithm is still `O(n)`).

Comment: Wouldn't your operation after sorting be more like O(m) where m is the number of repeated characters?

Comment: Assuming you're using a fixed-range fixed-size table, extraction of a value is `O(1)`. Think raw memory access and pointer arithmetic, for example.